# DDD: is that a Unit Of Work?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, ddd-repositories

I'm trying to apply DDD principles to an application built on top of [Doctrine 2.1](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.1/docs/en). To abstract the storage details, I'm using Repositories for my Aggregate Roots, with a strong Contract with the domain. These repositories hide all the implementation details and have to be the only way we can store or retrieve aggregates.

I need to create a class which will be the only entry point to the storage, and which will only have these methods:

```
class X
{
    public function getRepository($className) {}
    public function beginTransaction() {}
    public function rollback() {}
    public function commit() {}
}
```

[Unit Of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) has many definitions, and while some people think about it as just a way to abstract your transaction, others seem to consider it a quite low-level object knowing a lot of details about your domain objects (the Fowler definition is maybe closer to that).

So, is my `class X` a Unit Of Work, or does this pattern have another name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your class X is a Unit Of Work. Unit Of Work responsibilities are usually implemented by ORM but I think that there is an advantage in wrapping it into your own Unit Of Work class. So that your application code does not have a reference to ORM making it harder to bypass Unit Of Work and Repositories.